# Slack bot open message with group

Tags: slack-api

Currently I use the webhook method for my "bot" to send messages to team members.

This is great so far:

```php
$curl = curl_init('https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/YYY/ZZZ');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($message));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

The messages are encoded as JSON as per https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments

We use this to send exception reports to individuals. Some exception reports require my project administrator to follow up. (An exception might be "you didn't fill in your calendar for next week.")

I believe it could improve accountability if rather than a robot sending messages directly to a team member, the robot could send the message to the team member and the project administrator.

For direct message we can use

```php
'channel' => '@' . $row['responsible_person'],
```

but the obvious

```php
'channel' => '@' . $row['responsible_person'] . ',@projectadmin',
```

does not work.

Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I am aware, it is not possible to send a single message to two different users. A thought though -- what about sending the same message to the two different users **independently**?

Comment: Yes, you can send messages to a group of people. Its called Group DM. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send a message to several users at once with Slack. Its calls "multi-person direct message" or Group DM or MPIM and here is how it works:

1. Open the new MPIM channel with [conversations.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open) and provide the user IDs with the `users` property. This will return the ID of the MPIM channel and also create the channel if needed.
2. Use the channel ID to post your messages as you would with any other channel.

Note that this channel will consist of the members you invited and your bot user.

See also [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/conversations-api#use_the_conversations_api_for_anything_channel-like) for an overview of all channel types in Slack.